# Convert Android Intent Filter to Xamarin.Android Compatible Format

Tags: android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am re-writing an NFC App from standard Android/Java to Xamarin.Android so I can take advantage of cross platform features. I need help to translate the following Intent Filters to Xamarin.Android compatible format

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/techlist" />.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Finally got this working like so:

```
[Activity(Label = "AppName", MainLauncher = true), IntentFilter(new[] 
 { "android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" },       
    Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" })]
    [MetaData("android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED", Resource="@xml/techlist") ]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
```